# Set spell checking language

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization, spellchecker

Version 11 brings [real-time multilingual spell checking](http://www.wolfram.com/language/11/user-interface-enhancements/multilingual-spellchecking.html).  The linked page says,

> The language is automatically detected as you type, **but it can also be set manually.**

How do I set the spell checking language without changing the user-interface language?

Comment: That's a very interesting question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I do not know where there is a way to set this in the Preferences dialog, but it is changeable in the Options Inspector: search for "DefaultNaturalLanguage" and change the value of the drop-down. For example, with English as the interface language, changing the DefaultNaturalLanguage to Spanish causes English words to be flagged, as expected, but the interface does not change.

[image]

Comment: Hello. I have version 11.1.1.0 with an english user interface on MacOS 10.12.6. I am currently editing a notebook with a text in French. I did set DefaultNaturalLanguage for the notebook as indicated here, but each (correctly spelled) french word keeps being detected as a spelling error (red zigzag). I am missing something. Can someone please help ?

PS. Note that a multilingual text is correctly checked on the text editor of the system, so the problem is from within Mathematica.

Answer (score 18):

To change the [`DefaultNaturalLanguage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultNaturalLanguage.html) for the current notebook for example to `"German"` one can use

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DefaultNaturalLanguage] = "German"
```

The default is

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DefaultNaturalLanguage] = Language
```

`CurrentValue[Language]` gives the actual current value of the default.

Comment: Same problem with Mathematica 13.1. Did someone saw this multilingual spell check working ?