# Is there a tool for editing the spelling dictionary?

Tags: customization, configuration, dictionary, spellchecker

Is there a tool for editing the spelling dictionary? Now that *Mathematica* 12 does spellchecking on the fly, I've been using it.  And of course, as I was wondering how I might delete a word accidentally added to the dictionary, I accidentally added a misspelled word to the dictionary. I'm sure I can hunt it down and edit it by hand, but it seems safer to use a proper tool if one exists.  Is there one?

Comment: Open the options inspector under edit->Preferences->Advanced, lookup `SpellingDictionaries`, edit the `CorrectWords` entry...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For removing a misspelled word from the correct word list, go to Edit->Preferences, select the Advanced tab, select Open Option Inspector, lookup/search for SpellingDictionaries, click on the edit button for the CorrectWords entry, highlight the incorrect entry and select remove.

[image]

Comment: Apparently that change doesn't apply to the current session.  At least that's what I experienced.

Comment: Can there be other hidden locations for accidental additions?  Or does Mma actually recognize Euclidian (vs Euclidean) as a correct word, which just happened in my v.12.

Comment: @Alan Please see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

[Answer by ciao](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198308/280) shows a way to edit user-supplied list of correct words via GUI. The same can be done via setting `$FrontEnd` option:

```
Options[$FrontEnd, SpellingDictionaries]
```

> ```
> {SpellingDictionaries -> {"CorrectWords" -> {}, "IncorrectWords" -> {}, "Suggestions" -> {}}}
> ```

The meaning of the sub-options is [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpellingDictionaries.html):

> - `"CorrectWords"->{"word1",""word2"",...}` means that if any word in the list is found during a spell check, it is skipped even if it does
>     not exist in the main dictionary.
> - `"IncorrectWords"->{"word1",""word2"",...}` means that if any word in the list is found, the spell check stops, even if the word exists
>     in the main dictionary.
> - `"Suggestions"->{{"word1"->"newword1"},...}` means that if any word in the list is found, the spell check stops and the corresponding new
>     word is offered as an alternative in the **Check Spelling** dialog
>     box.

Note that there is also the `"IncorrectWords"` option with rather strange *documented* meaning: "... if any word in the list is found, the spell check **stops**...". I would assume that the spell checking doesn't *stop* at such word but rather marks it as misspelled.

---

> Can there be other hidden locations for accidental additions? Or does Mma actually recognize Euclidian (vs Euclidean) as a correct word, which just happened in my v.12.

Searching through all textual files in the directory

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", "SpellingData", "SpellingDictionaries"}]
```

reveals that the whole word "Euclidian" is indeed present in the files "en_Supplemental.dic" and "ro_RO.dic" located in that directory. So it looks like the word "Euclidian" is indeed considered as a correct word by *Mathematica*'s spellchecker because it is included in one of the basic dictionaries for English. We can try to add this word to the list of incorrect words via the `"IncorrectWords"` option:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, SpellingDictionaries -> {"IncorrectWords" -> {"Euclidian"}}]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't have any effect: even after restarting *Mathematica* this word isn't marked as misspelled. I would consider this as a bug.

P.S. It is also interesting that this word is present in the file

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", "OpenPHACTS", "Kernel", "OpenPHACTS.m"}]
```

---

**UPDATE1**. I've moved the file "en_Supplemental.dic" outside of the `$InstallationDirectory` and then restarted *Mathematica*. After the restart the word "euclidian" is still considered as correctly spelled. So there seems to be some other place from where the spellchecker takes it...

**UPDATE2**. The word "Euclidian" is so well-protected that even [setting the language of spell checking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123510/280) to Russian doesn't affect it: now all usual English words are marked as misspelled including the word "Euclidean" but *excepting* the word "Euclidian":

[image: screenshot]

**UPDATE3**. Searching for the word "euclidian" in the all files in the `$InstallationDirectory` (including binary files) reveals that it is present in the following files:

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,"Documentation","English","Index","_e.cfs"}]
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,"Documentation","English","SearchIndex","2","_1.cfs"}]
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,"Documentation","English","SpellIndex","_19s.cfs"}]
```

Especially suspicious is the file in the directory "SpellIndex". But even moving this directory outside of `$InstallationDirectory` and restarting *Mathematica* doesn't change the described behavior...

**UPDATE4**. The `Entity` framework considers the words "euclidean" and "euclidian" as synonyms:

```
Entity["Word", "euclidian"]@EntityProperty["Word", "SynonymsList"]
Entity["Word", "euclidean"]@EntityProperty["Word", "SynonymsList"]
```

> ```
> {"euclidean"}
>
> {"euclidian"}
> ```