# Which words are "protected" from the built-in spell checker?

Tags: bugs, front-end, spellchecker

**Bug persists through 13.2** [CASE:4331923]

---

Some time ago [Alan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19530/alan) raised an interesting question about spell checking in *Mathematica* in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198298/is-there-a-tool-for-editing-the-spelling-dictionary#comment528097_198308):

> <...> does Mma actually recognize Euclidian (vs Euclidean) as a correct word, which just happened in my v.12.

[Experimenting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207019/280) with the spell checking options and this word revealed that it seems to be a "protected" word which can't be touched by *Mathematica*'s spellchecker independently on the language settings and other options. The most bright evidence is that [setting the language of spell checking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123510/280) to Russian doesn't affect this word: now all usual English words are marked as misspelled including the word "Euclidean" but excepting the word "Euclidian". Try:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, DefaultNaturalLanguage] = "Russian";

CellPrint[TextCell["Euclidean Euclidian русский текст ddd dddd ", "Text"]]
```

[image: screenshot]

It was a very surprising discovery. What could be a reason for this? Are there other "protected from spellchecker" words in *Mathematica*?